# Как вывести определенное значение в html

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, api

Вопрос очень простой но при этом я попал в какой-то тупик, получаю массив с api и хочу вывести его в html, а именно значение score

```html
/tmp/phpFh1f8Warray(2) {
  ["quality"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["score"]=>
    float(0.7031919360160828)
  }
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
}
```

Подскажите как это сделать с помощью javascript?

Сам запрос у меня на php и я решил этот вопрос, но не могу вывести в нужном мне месте, поэтому решил отбросить и попробовать сделать на js

```html
<?php
$authorization = "SRd6kjgk6pPuGoDdl2kO3Mbt" . ":" . "DQIRvCnwinFJt4CgLQWuxiWIUNjTeq2mtar74KdRcILyLvpw";
$url = "https://api.everypixel.com/v1/quality?";
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
print($filedata);
if ($filedata != '')
{
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 
$postfields = [
    'data' => new \CurlFile($filedata, 'image/png', $filename)
];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $authorization);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $filesize);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json = str_replace('Array ( ) ', '', $json);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($json);
}
?>
```

Comment: Можете предоставить код запроса?

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос